# How to create 2 gram shingles?

Tags: python

I have this code which i got from some tutorial-:

```
list1 = [['hello','there','you','too'],['hello','there','you','too','there'],['there','you','hello']]

def get_shingle(size,f):
    #shingles = set()
    for i in range (0,len(f)-2+1):
        yield f[i:i+2]

#shingles1 = set(get_shingle(list1[0],2))
#shingles2 = set(get_shingle(list1[1],2))
shingles1 = set(get_shingle(2,list1[0]))
shingles2 = set(get_shingle(2,list1[1]))

print shingles1
print shingles2
print "done"
```

When i try to run this code i am getting an error -:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Research\Shingle Method\create_shingle.py", line 10, in <module>
    shingles1 = set(get_shingle(2,list1[0]))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If list1 is set then the error does not come. But i cannot convert list1 into set as **it removes duplicate words** and also i need it to be a list for my major code which processes a huge text file in the form of list. 
Why am i getting this 'unhashable list'? Can't we pass list as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that your get_shingle() function yields `lists`.
Lists are not hashable, which is needed to build a set. You can easily solve this by yielding a tuple (which is hashable), instead of a list.

Transform the following line in your code:

```
yield tuple(f[i:i+2])
```

This will result in the following:

```
list1 = [['hello','there','you','too'],['hello','there','you','too','there'],['there','you','hello']]

def get_shingle(size,f):
    #shingles = set()
    print(f)
    for i in range (0,len(f)-2+1):
        yield tuple(f[i:i+2])

shingles1 = { i for i in get_shingle(2,list1[0])}
print(shingles1)
```

and outputs:

```
['hello', 'there', 'you', 'too']
{('you', 'too'), ('hello', 'there'), ('there', 'you')}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Because the `yield` command returns a generator. The conversion of a generator to a set is triggering the unhashable type error.

You can make your code work by a simple alteration.

```
shingles1 = get_shingle(2,list1[0])
lst = [x for x in shingles1]
```

This will give you all the bigrams from `list1[0]` and put it into `lst`

Answer (score 1):

Yield command generates a generator and set(iterator) expects an iterator which is immutable

So something like this will work

```
shingles1 = set(get_shingle(2,list1[0]))
set(tuple(x) for x in shingles1)
```